# DMGR and Node Agent - Different versions

Tags: websphere

To start with i have limited knowledge on Web sphere application/configurations. With that being said, recently i had applied IBM fix patch and upgraded to 8.5.5.13 on server A. Looks like Server B deployment manager with version 8.5.5.2 is using the node agent on server A. So i have two different versions of web spheres and i see blow error in the logs.

`FFDC Exception:com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.exception.DiscardQueryException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.DiscoveryService.processQuery ProbeId:278 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.DiscoveryService@a995a69f
com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.exception.DiscardQueryException: The version of the Deployment Manager (8.5.5.2) is earlier than that of the nodeagent (8.5.5.13)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.DiscoveryService.processQuery(DiscoveryService.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.DiscoveryService.demux(DiscoveryService.java:518)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.Endpoint.demux(Endpoint.java:196)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.discovery.transport.TcpConnection.run(TcpConnection.java:193)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)`

Can someone help me with any recommendations why its failing and possible fixes. I know it you may suggest to make both versions in sync. Do i have any other options? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message is informing you of the problem:
The version of the Deployment Manager (8.5.5.2) is earlier than that of the nodeagent (8.5.5.13)

Your Deployment Manager should be updated first, it has to be at the same or more recent service level as nodes in the cell.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Can DMGR alone be updated or its web sphere that i need to update? Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You'd be updating your WebSphere installation (which contains your Deployment Manager profile)

Comment: Thanks @Dan for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment manager [must be at or above](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/cmig_overview.html) the level of all nodes it is managing (relevant quote from link: "The deployment manager has to be at the level of the highest node version".) There really isn't a way around that restriction that I know of. You can either roll back the node or update the deployment manager.

Comment: I have issue in rolling back. The other best option as of now is to update the web sphere in server B.